# What's the best way to define a list of pre-initialized objects in a module?

Tags: python

I use scientific code, and I store the parameters for the calculations in two parameter classes. I want to have an easy way to preserve different values, so I set up a module containing nothing but a collection of predefined objects. These are stored in a dictionary. The key name as a string is used in different places, this is why I didn't choose a tuple-variable for each.

But the way I store the data looks a bit unorthodox to me:

```
from PlaceholderName import field, meshfield
paramlist = {}

########################################################################################
name = "Parameter1"

fieldparams = field.FieldParameters(
     compname    = "pu_e_r_nrif"
    ,n1          = 1.0
    ,lambda0     = 0.800
    # etc., about 15 parameters
)
meshparams = meshfield.MeshParameters(
     rmax        = 6 #um
    ,zmin        = -10 #um 
    # etc., about 5 parameters
)
paramlist[name] = (fieldparams, meshparams)

########################################################################################
name = "Parameter2"

fieldparams = field.FieldParameters(
    # (...)
)
meshparams = meshfield.MeshParameters(
    # (...)
)
paramlist[name] = (fieldparams, meshparams)

########################################################################################
name = "Parameter3"

# and so on, 10s of entries like this...
```

Point is that the resulting code is easy to edit and oversee; it's just like a data text file. It's also super easy to use, as one has to only import, the `paramlist` dictionary, and access to the parameter as `paramlist['name']`.

Still, this is an approach that I never seen, and seems a bit unorthodox. Is there a more standard way of achieving my goal?

Note that this is not a production, but a scientific code, and users of the code are expected to make changes in the source.

Comment: Have you considered JSON?

Comment: That seems horrible to me. Separate your code and the data, use an existing data format (https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html, https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html, https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html, https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html are built into the standard library, for example, third party libraries add support for YAML, TOML, ...).

Comment: @TookieWookie Yes, but I think JSON would result in more complicated access to the variables, wouldn't it? Right now only an import is needed, json would need a reader function.

Comment: Then go with `yaml` or XML or something. I don't understand this at all

Comment: The Python standard library `json` module can convert json directly into a Python dictionary. I doubt you are going to get simpler than that

Comment: Maybe this will help you? https://github.com/drgrib/dotmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both for readability purposes and to follow the [rule of least power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_least_power), I would recommend storing the data in a simple text format, rather than as code.

Although this does require some parsing code, it doesn't have to be prohibitively complex. For example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Parameter1",
    "field": {
      "compname": "pu_e_r_nrif",
      "n1": 1.0,
      "lambda0": 0.8,
      ...
    },
    "mesh": {
      "rmax": 6,
      "zmin": -10,
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

can easily be parsed and converted as follows (using a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)):

```
import json

from PlaceholderName import field, meshfield

with open("path/to/file") as config_file:
    paramlist = {
      param['name']: (
        field.FieldParameters(**param['field']),
        meshfield.MeshParameters(**param['mesh'])
      ) 
      for param in json.load(config_file)
    }
```

Note that:

- the configuration now *is* a plain data file, not code mangled to look like one, so it can be easily syntax checked* with simple tools and without knowing details of any specific programming language;
- it [separates code and data](https://wiki.c2.com/?SeparationOfDataAndCode), so the data is much safer to pass around (e.g. over a network) than something you actually have to execute; and
- there is less duplication of the boilerplate code, as it's in a loop, meaning it's harder to make typos like missing out the `paramlist[name] = (fieldparams, meshparams)` for one of your pairs.

From the perspective of the rest of your program, the configuration is a simple import, exactly as before.

There are many other text formats you could use to represent the data, like YAML (although that would require a third-party library):

```yaml
---
- name: Parameter1
  field:
    compname: pu_e_r_nrif
    n1: 1.0
    lambda0: 0.8
    ...
  mesh:
    rmax: 6
    zmin: -10
    ...
- ...
```

---

* or even checked against a schema, using e.g. [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
    "$id": "http://example.com/config.schema.json",
    "title": "JSON schema for config.json",
    "type": "array",
    "contains": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
            "name",
            "field",
            "mesh"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "description": "The name of the parameter, must be unique",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "field": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "compname",
                    "n1",
                    "lambda0"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "compname": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "n1": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "lambda0": {
                        "type": "number"
                    }
                }
            },
            "mesh": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "rmax",
                    "zmin"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "rmax": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "zmin": {
                        "type": "number"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```